# getting error for AbstractMixedCollection.js?_dc=1343805300426

Tags: extjs

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'id': object is null or undefined 
AbstractMixedCollection.js?_dc=1343805300426, line 147 character 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved, there was some error in Extjs code. The semicolon was missing at the end of the sentence.